# Getting from a MockedFunction to Mock

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-extension, types, jestjs, type-conversion

I'm trying to use an assertion from [jest-extend](https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended#tohavebeencalledbefore) on a mock created by [jest-chrome](https://github.com/extend-chrome/jest-chrome).
Here is the code:

```
expect(chrome.tabs.update).toHaveBeenCalledAfter(chrome.cookies.set);
```

But Typescript throws the following error:

> error TS2345: Argument of type 'MockedFunction<(details: SetDetails,
> callback?: (cookie: Cookie) => void) => void>' is not assignable to
> parameter of type 'Mock<any, any>'.

Converting to any:
`expect(chrome.tabs.update).toHaveBeenCalledAfter(chrome.cookies.set as any);`

solves the problem and everything works as expected.
Is there a better way to make Typescript compile this code (without converting to any)?

Comment: Please [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)